# How do I intercept failures of a Gradle task?

Tags: gradle, jmeter, gradle-plugin

'I'm writing build script using net.foragerr.jmeter plug-in, version 1.0.2-2.13.

What my task does is mostly 1) runs plug-in JMeter task and 2) collects application log.

```
task perfTest(dependsOn: ['jmClean', 'jmRun'],
  description:'Runs (cleanly) performance tests on a deployed application and collects the app log if available. ' +
  'Use --no-daemon to see progress. Use --info to see all JMeter command-line arguments.') << {

    if (logDir.isDirectory()) {
        copy {
            from "${logDir}"
            into "${buildDir}/jmeter-report"
            include 'iRePORT.log'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to collect the log even if `jmRun` fails. When I try to implement a solution for this, I am really stuck:

1. I can't modify `jmRun` task, because it's a plug-in task
2. I can't use `try/finally` and execute another task directly because Gradle is  designed not to support this, e.g. see [How do I wrap a gradle task in another task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617977/how-do-i-wrap-a-gradle-task-in-another-task)
3. I can't use `--continue` flag `gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true` because it would not continue execution of a dependent task

The only possible workaround that I could think of is to separate log collection, always include it on a command line, e.g. `perfTest collectLogs` and set `gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true` in `perfTest`.

This is far from ideal.

Are there any better solutions? Shouldn't there be a way for Gradle to support scenarios like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a task like this

```
task collectPerfTestLogs(type: Copy) {
   from "${logDir}"
   into "${buildDir}/jmeter-report"
   include 'iRePORT.log'
}
```

and then have `perfTest.finalizedBy(collectPerfTestLogs)`.

To quote Gradle:

> Finalizer tasks will be executed even if the finalized task fails.

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks! I did not know about finalizedBy().